# OutboundEmail error: Content is not allowed in prolog., Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: 2011, audience-manager, outbound-email

I have to do updates on a newsletter subscription page created by a colleague from me.
When I try to submit the page on our dev and production environment I get following error:

> Configuration error: Content is not allowed in prolog., Content is not allowed in prolog.

And this when using following line of code

```
Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentDelivery.Profile.Contact contact = new Contact();
```

A part of the Stack Trace is

> [IOException: Configuration error: Content is not allowed in prolog., Content is not allowed in prolog.]
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst) +519
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst) +1258
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo) +583
>      Com.Tridion.Marketingsolution.Profile.Contact..ctor() +57
>      Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentDelivery.Profile.Contact..ctor() +346

Tridion is upgraded more then a year ago from 2009 to 2011 SP1.

Is there someone who had the same issue and know how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the web.config the appsetting "ConfigurationFile" was still pointing to the properties file instead of cd_audience_manager_conf.xml.

In the web.config I had following line

```
    <add key="ConfigurationFile" value="OutboundEmail.properties" />
```

Changing it to

```
    <add key="ConfigurationFile" value="cd_audience_manager_conf.xml" />
```

resolved the error message.

My contact is stored that's for sure because I get a message "A contact with the same identification already exists" when I submitted the form for a second time.  Only thing I have to sort out is "where?" but I will first check the configuration before I open a new question ;-)

Comment: I don't see the point of having this config in the web.config file <add key="ConfigurationFile" value="cd_audience_manager_conf.xml" />, you just should have this file in the config folder.

Comment: SDL mention in the installation manual of Tridion to include this appsetting together with some other settings.  They don't give more information about this setting in the manual.  So it's indeed possible that this setting is not needed but that's something people can't know based on the documentation of SDL.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there's a problem parsing your configuration as XML (cd_audience_manager_conf.xml). Based on the error message, it could be a problem with Byte Order Marks. Could you try opening and saving the file with an encoding that doesn't use a BOM?

For instance, you can open it in Notepad and remove the first character (*if* it looks like a garbage character) and then save it.

Comment: I checked cd_audience_manager_conf.xml and convert it to UTF-8 without BOM but didn't solve the issue.  I did the same for the OutBoundEmail.properties file but without luck. Maybe other files I need to check?

Comment: The properties file was replaced with cd_audience_manager_conf.xml so you can delete that one. I'm fairly sure the problem is with cd_audience_manager_conf.xml as that is the one it loads in the constructor of Contact and the error is about invalid XML. Perhaps you could open it in an XML editor or Internet Explorer and see if they have issues with it too?

Comment: cd_audience_manager_conf.xml is displayed without errors in Internet Explorer.  Maybe interesting that I search for an example conf file in the packages of Tridion so that I can compare the files.